# Is there any way to do a bulk/faster delete in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 10 million records, what is the fastest way to delete & retain last 30 days.

I know this can be done in event scheduler, but my worry is if takes too much time, it might lock the table for much time.

It will be great if you can suggest some optimum way.

Thanks.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 - once you reduce the table to just 30-days worth of data, how many records will be left?  10 million?

Comment: Have you got auto-commit off, set transaction etc...?

Answer (score 5):

Offhand, I would:

1. Rename the table
2. Create an empty table with the same name as your
   original table
3. Grab the last 30 days from your "temp" table and insert
   them back into the new table
4. Drop the temp table

This will enable you to keep the table live through (almost) the entire process and get the past 30 days worth of data at your leisure.

Comment: Depending on how available the data needs to be, another option would be to 1. Grab the last 30 days into a new table 2. Switch the two tables (so the new table is the main one) 3. Move anything that was added to the old table during the switch (probably very little).

Comment: @Brendan That's certainly a more fault-tolerant solution.

Comment: No this has to be automated.I can't rename the table, as its accessed by application.

Answer (score 4):

You could try partition tables.

```
PARTITION BY LIST (TO_DAYS( date_field ))
```

This would give you 1 partition per day, and when you need to prune data you just:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP PARTITION p#
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 1):

Not that it helps you with your current problem, but if this is a regular occurance, you might want to look into a [merge table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html): just add tables for different periods in time, and remove them from the `merge` table definition when no longer needed. Another option is [partitioning](http://www.pythian.com/news/14971/using-mysql-partitioning-instead-of-merge-tables/), in which it is equally trivial to drop a (oldest) partition.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Michael Todd's answer.

If you have the space,

1. Create a blank staging table similar to the table you want to reduce in size
2. Fill the staging table with only the records you want to have in your destination table
3. Do a double rename like the following

Assuming:
table is the table name of the table you want to purge a large amount of data from
newtable is the staging table name
no other tables are called temptable

```
    rename table table to temptable, newtable to table;
    drop temptable;
```

This will be done in a single transaction, which will require an instantaneous schema lock.  Most high concurrency applications won't notice the change.

Alternatively, if you don't have the space, and you have a long window to purge this data, you can use dynamic sql to insert the primary keys into a temp table, and join the temp table in a delete statement.  When you insert into the temp table, be aware of what max_packet_size is.  Most installations of MySQL use 16MB (16777216 bytes).  Your insert command for the temp table should be under max_packet_size.  This will not lock the table.  You'll want to run optimize table to reclaim space for the rest of the engine to use.  You probably won't be able to reclaim disk space, unless you were to shutdown the engine and move the data files.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown your resource, 
`SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`, parse output, delete table, `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE optimized_db.txt` - more cheaper to re-create, than to UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks, i do using select into & load data to take data backup before the records can be deleted.Its like 7-8 million records has to be deleted while 10 million has to be backed up for archiving purpose.